# OutputStream is not available in ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, outputstream

I work with ASP.Net MVC 4.
I'm encountering a situation where I have no solutions and you might help me a suggestion.
I want my action to download a zipped file with some PDF and DOCX files. The part with the zipping works fine, but when I return the File(...) I get this error:

```
    Exception: System.Web.HttpException
    Message: OutputStream is not available when a custom TextWriter is used.
    Source: System.Web
      at System.Web.HttpResponse.get_OutputStream()
      at System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult.WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

I would like to mention that the FileStream is closed before the return. Also same code works in ASP.Net Web Forms.
This is my code from my Listcontroller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Download()
    {
        return View(somedatatodownload);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public FileResult Index()
    {
       FileStream zipStream = new FileStream(path + filename, FileMode.Open);
       long FileSize = zipStream.Length;
       byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
       zipStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)zipStream.Length);
       zipStream.Close();
       return File(Buffer, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip, filename);
    }
```

And this is my code from View:

```
    @{
         Html.BeginForm("Index", "List", FormMethod.Post);
     }
     <div>
        <input type="submit" name="download" value="Download all zipped" />
    </div>
     @{
          Html.EndForm();
      }
```

**Note**: This is my first post, so don't be mad at me if I did something wrong!

Comment: Is this the only code in your `Index` action?

Comment: Is this the actual code that can reproduce the problem? As you are just reading an existing zip into memory and then not using it. So that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seem like it's a problem with the HTML TextWriter, you can try a simple workaround to make it works.

```
<form action="List/Index" method="POST"> <div>
    <input type="submit" name="download" value="Download all zipped" />
</div></form
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked with

```
@Html.ActionLink("Some text", "Controller", "Action that returns FileResult")
```